# Deploying Firebase functions not working with engines.node =12...?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy some Firebase cloud functions and with the Firebase versions as:

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^7.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.9.0"
  },
```

Node is version 12.18.3, but when I try to deploy functions with engines.node set to 12 in package.json, I get an error that the only valid choices are: {"node": "8"} and {"node": "10"}

I can successfully deploy with it set to 10, but the documentation says it works with 12. Is package.json the wrong place to set that version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade your Firebase CLI version [8.6.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v8.6.0), since that was the first version where node 12 is supported.